# Can't mount dd image - shows correct used space

Tags: backup, 17.04, dd

So one of my HD starting to give me Input/Output errors 1.5 weeks ago and I immediately went into '***backup***' mode. The drive in question is a 4TB HD and I have created a dd image of it already *(took 5 days)* and stored on my recently purchased NAS device.

The issue(s) I have is that for the life of me, I cannot mount this image in order to push the files to my new NAS folder, I get quite a few errors.

After spending about almost a week Googling and researching various methods, I thought it was time to ask the professionals here. After reading various threads and seeing common repsonses to the OP thread, I'll put some of the commands and output here.

**Original DD command to create the copy:**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdf2 of=/home/sga/media/Recovered/movies-recovered.iso bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

As mentioned, this took 5 days to backup the 4TB drive, but it did and it's there.

**Now the issue is when I try to mount it, I get errors:**

```
sga@Media-Server:~$ sudo mount /home/sga/media/Recovered/movies-recovered.iso /home/sga/media/Movies-Bak/

ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x29d25a8d  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 11352  usa_count: 12859: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x7d9e7dde443abaf1) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x30).
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x29d25a8d  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 11352  usa_count: 12859: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x7d9e7dde443abaf1) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x30).
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x29d25a8d  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 11352  usa_count: 12859: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x7d9e7dde443abaf1) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x30).
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x29d25a8d  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 11352  usa_count: 12859: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x7d9e7dde443abaf1) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x30).
ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Device or resource busy
```

Now the weird bit, when I run a `df -h` it shows the folder location of where I attempted to mount AND it shows the **correct USED** space and the **correct FREE** space on the `/dev/loop1`... but I can't access any files in the drive.

```
sga@Media-Server:Movies-Bak$ df -h
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                             3.2G   11M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda1                         426G   41G  365G  10% /
tmpfs                              16G   28K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                              16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdf2                         3.7T  3.3T  433G  89% /home/sga/media/Movies
/dev/sde2                         1.4T   55G  1.4T   4% /home/sga/media/Movies-2
/dev/sdb1                         1.9T   85G  1.8T   5% /home/sga/media/Dev-Server
/dev/sdd2                         3.7T  3.4T  341G  91% /home/sga/media/TV-Series
/dev/sdc2                         3.7T  3.0T  755G  80% /home/sga/media/TV-Series-Cont
tmpfs                             3.2G  132K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
192.168.1.113:/volume1/Recovered   11T  4.0T  6.5T  38% /home/sga/media/Recovered
/dev/loop1                        4.0T  3.6T  433G  90% /home/sga/media/Movies-Bak
```

Think anyone can give me a hand?

Thanks!!